# Express.js/Node.js Responses Before Query Finishes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, esp8266

I have a local server that is **fully functioning** when POSTs and GETs are sent from Postman or chrome rest apps etc. However, whenever I send it from an ESP8266 it fails as it follows:

This is my server side code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var person = req.query.id;
console.log("1");
Person.find({person: personID} ,function (err, station) {
    if(err) console.log(err.message);

    console.log("3");
    res.send('test');
    console.log("4");
});

console.log("2");
});
```

Lines below are from console when request is sent from **Chrome**.

```
1
2
3
4
GET /api?id=ABKWTltz6Ug 200 21.829 ms - -
```

And the lines below are from console when request is sent from **ESP8266**.

```
1
2
GET /api?id=ABKWTltz6Ug - - ms - -
3
4
```

As you may notice logs 3 and 4 are **after** GET response line. My ESP8266 TCP connection lines match the [HTTP Message Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_Format):

```
GET /api HTTP/1.1
Host: *SERVER_IP_ADDRESS*
```

The problem raised when we switched from PHP to NodeJS backend server. ESP8266 used to connect and operate without problems back then. And FYI, everything also works fine if I remove the Person.find code block and move the res.send('test'); outside.

Another freshly written backend code to hopefully spot the error is below. This is the whole code. Which also returns the same error I've mentioned earlier above:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');


app.use(morgan('dev'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


//mongoose.Promise = Promise;
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', { name: String });

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {

    console.log("1");
    var test1 = new Test({
      name: "Name"
    });

    var query = test1.save();

    query.then(function (doc) {
        res.send('1').end();
        console.log('3');
    });

    console.log("2");
});

app.use('/api', router);

var port = 9000;
app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('server started on', port);

});
```

Comment: Is that your whole code, or are you using `res` somewhere else in `router.get('/',...)` ?

Comment: I do notice that there is no response code and response time for `GET /api?id=ABKWTltz6Ug - - ms - -`

Could you please try `res.send('test').end();`?

Comment: @ravishankar yes this is the whole code. i'm attaching the code to the end of the question.

Comment: @Pingster I tried. nothing changed.

Comment: If `res` falls out of scope during the db query then the HTTP request could end prematurely.  You could try setting it into a local variable and referring to the local variable in your `then`.

Comment: @leetibbett that is unfortunately not the case. Still issuing such awkwardness